# Python - get variables from file using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

#### Problem

Given a file, for example:

```
#Example
x = 'foo = {}'

bar = {
  'color': 'blue'
}

print('Hello World')
```

**Using regular expressions**, the program will find variables names that are corresponding to **dictionaries** or **set literals** and print them. The output for the above would just be:

```
bar
```

A line like this

```
yes = { "no={}" }
```

Should only return yes.

---

The variables could be found with \w+? expression I'm just not sure where to start.

#### Current code

```
for line in open('program.txt'):
   array = line.split(' ')

   for item in array:
      if '{' in item:
         print(array[0])
```

*This only functions properly for basic examples and there are some problems. Multiable variables on the same line don't work either. Also it doesn't use Regular Expressions.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do like this,

```
>>> s = '''#Example
x = 'foo = {}'

bar = {
  'color': 'blue'
}

print('Hello World')
yes = { "no={}" }'''
>>> re.findall(r'^\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*\{[^}]*\}', s, re.M)
['bar', 'yes']
```

**or**

```
>>> [i for i in re.findall(r'\{(?:\{[^{}]*\}|[^{}])*\}|^\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*(?=\{)', s, re.M) if i]
['bar', 'yes']
>>>
```

If you want to define it as a function, you may use the below.

```
def check(s):
    return [i for i in re.findall(r'\{(?:\{[^{}]*\}|[^{}])*\}|^\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*(?=\{)', s, re.M) if i]
```

Comment: How would I modify the pattern so that it can find dictionaries in one line functions. Example: def check(): b = {} would output b.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regular expressions for this.

Well, that's probably a bit too strong.  Don't *just* use regular expressions for this.

Start by matching the code against this regex:

```
(\w+)\s*=\s*(.*)
```

Then, take the second capturing group, and pass it through [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

To wit:

```
results = {}
for line in file:
    match = re.match(r'(\w+)\s*=\s*(.*)')
    if match:
        try:
            results[match.group(1)] = ast.literal_eval(match.group(2))
        except ValueError:
            continue  # It wasn't a valid literal
```

Note that `ast.literal_eval()` does not handle set and byte literals in 2.x.  This is yet another reason to upgrade to Python 3.